# breeze error trying delete a entity

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I am new in breeze and i am trying delete a entity using this code:

```
export var deleteRow= function (selectedRow) {
   isDeleting(true);
   selectedRow.entityAspect.setDeleted();
   (<any>datacontext).saveChanges()
       .done(
        function () {
           router.replaceLocation(listUrl);
         })
       .fail(saveFailed);
    //}
  isDeleting(false);
};
```

and the datacontext is:

```
 export var saveChanges = function () {
    return manager.saveChanges()
        .then(saveSucceeded)
        .fail(saveFailed);

    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
            log('Saved data successfully', saveResult, true);
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        var msg = 'Save failed: ' + getErrorMessages(error);
        logError(msg, error);
        error.message = msg;
        throw error;
    }
};
```

The error happend in line:

```
selectedRow.entityAspect.setDeleted();
```

The log (chrome console) tell something about:

"Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'dictionary' of null;
Bindings value: text: row.assessmentType().dictionary().name "

the object row it's alias used in my markup to identify a row in my collection:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: { data: assessmentRegistrations(), as: 'row' }-->
                    <tr data-bind="css: { koAssumptionGridViewRow: true }, style: { color: 'inherit' }">                                   
                        <td><small data-bind="text: row.toShortDate"></small></td>
                        <td><small data-bind="text: row.fishgroup().fishgroupName"></small></td>
                        <td><small data-bind="text: row.assessmentType().dictionary().name"></small></td>                                   
                        <td><small data-bind="text: row.site().name"></small></td>
                        <td><small data-bind="text: row.site().name"></small></td>                                      
                        <td></td>                                  
                        <td><small data-bind="text: row.assessmentFollowUpStatus().dictionary().name"></small></td>                           
                    </tr>
```

any help is apreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is but I would try to isolate it first. i.e. without involving any knockout binding try to call *setDeleted()*.  My bet is that this will succeed. If so, then you know that the issue is a knockout binding issue.

Another possibility: Is it possible that the issue is actually occurring AFTER the saveChanges() call?  The reason why this would make sense given your symptoms is that a 'deleted' entity becomes 'detached' after a saveChanges() call and binding to it is very likely to fail.

Comment: i remove all binding code in my html view, and yes you right, it's working, so that it's a knockout issue. The strange here is why i am getting ko issues at the moment to run that line (setDeleted())...

Comment: Another possibility is that when you call setDeleted() Breeze effectively disconnects your entities from all of its relations to other entities.  So my guess is that your navigation properties begin to return null after calling setDeleted() and ko can't bind to this, especially if you try to access a property of a property, i.e. row.site().name where row.site === null;

Comment: Okay, what I did was a litle different. from my datacontext i got the Id of the object what i want to delete and after that i call to my api controller to delete the object and their children (about 140 rows for each parent). In any case I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you !